# Height of component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, mobile-application, react-native-stylesheet

[image]

As you see in the image, the styling of the component is as follows: <TouchableOpacity
style={{
height: listDataSource[item.key].isExpanded ? 500 : 140,
width: widthw * 0.8,
marginHorizontal: 12,
backgroundColor: 'red',
}}

Now when isExpanded is true my other item in the flat list moves to the top.

Can anyone please help how to stick the other item in bottom only?

Comment: please add codepen or codesandbox

Answer (score 1):

try this for flatlist

```
contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}
```